# Sequentially fill-up drives unRaid-way

Tags: linux, script, raid, storage

Is there a linux tool or script that will enable me to fill hard drives sequentially like with unRaid and grow my volume by adding drives when needed? I'm not after redundancy here.

It should put files in unchanged form (no split) to the drives. It should be seen as one directory by the system.

JBOD is what comes to mind but I don't want to loose all data on drive failure so when drive fails then there should leave regular files on another drives.

After some googling I didn't find an answer.

Comment: Do you mean to "Backup" your hard disk? Rsync with an external hard drive should work.

Comment: Thank you for contribution. Buckup/rsync is not what I'm aiming for. I need logical directory that will combine physical hard drives to be seen by a system as one uniform space that can be used by other apps.